# Pointing subdomain DNS to Google Apps location

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, g-suite

I want to point a sub domain to a google apps account, what is the best way to do this in DNS.

For example
email.example-site.com -> https://www.google.com/a/example-site.com.com

What should the DNS record look like?

Comment: Is it your own server or are you hosted with some company ?

Answer (score 5):

To point it to Google Apps, you need to set a CNAME that points to ghs.google.com. For instance:

```
email.example-site.com IN CNAME ghs.google.com.
```

You'll also need to configure your Google Apps account to allow this. In your Dashboard, click on the `Email` link and it should take you to your Email settings page. At the top, you should see a section called: `Web address`, with a link called `Change URL`. Go through the wizard and it should provide you with instructions on what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is outside the scope of DNS on it's own. You can however point DNS to a web server that then does a HTML redirect.

Comment: the Google Apps instructions specify that this is done at the DNS level with a CNAME record, not with an HTTP or HTML redirect.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set up your mx records as per Google's instructions.  If you want to set up a sub domain to access web mail you create a cname that points to ghs.google.com.

You have to validate the subdomain in your Google Docs dashboard before you can use it.

[image]

You should also set up spf records to prevent your mail going to spam boxes.

```
SPF Records:

example.com 14400 in TXT "v=spf1 include:aspmx.googlemail.com ~all"

example.com 14400 in TXT "v=spf1 a mx ip4:xxx.xxx.xx.xxx include:aspmx.googlemail
```